# Puppeteer always times out while trying to take a screenshot of any webpage

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com/');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

No matter what website I attempt to screenshot, I always get the following error:

```
(node:9548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
```

I'm running node version 8.16.0. I have no idea why I always get this timeout. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It does seem to work when I run it with headless mode turned off, but I need it to run as a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the navigation timeout:

```
await page.goto('https://google.com/', { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 50000 });
```

and add `try/catch`:

```
try {
 await page.goto('https://google.com/', { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 50000 });
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Error--->', e);
}
```

Comment: I have a try catch around the page.goto and it just displays the error i posted above. I increased the timeout to 50 seconds and it worked, but there's no way it should take 50 seconds to load google.com in a headless browser right? It only took 2 or 3 seconds on my coworkers laptop so we're not sure what's wrong